# CONSTRAINT на уникальные значения с условием

Tags: mysql, constraints

Есть таблица в mysql
колонки (id,custom_field_id ,value)

В таблицу необходимо установить ограничение на уникальные значения поля value, при условии что `custom_field_id = 7`
т.е с при остальных`custom_field_id` значения могут быть не уникальными

Answer (score 0):

MySQL на данный момент не умеет частичные индексы.

В MySQL 8.0.13 и новее можно [обойти так](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e591e7e2d39db060979f64292121b79):

```
create  table foo (custom_field_id int , value int);
create unique index idx1 on foo(value, (if(custom_field_id = 7, custom_field_id,  null)));
```

Вычисляемое значение вторым полем будет давать NULL для `custom_field_id != 7`, NULL не равен NULL, а потому уникальность нарушаться не будет. Для значения 7, в свою очередь же, уникальность будет проверяться по значению value.

---

В  ещё более старых версиях mysql придётся добавлять generated column в таблицу для вычисления выражения `if(custom_field_id = 7, custom_field_id,  null)` и включать в индекс это поле.

```
create  table foo (
  custom_field_id int , 
  val int, 
  cf7 int as (if(custom_field_id = 7, custom_field_id,  null)) virtual
);
create unique index idx1 on foo(val, cf7);
```

Comment: спасибо, но для значений, где custom_field_id != 7 в итоге будет присвоен NULL или первоначальное значение?

Comment: Само значение в custom_field_id, разумеется, не меняем.

Comment: отлично, добавил ещё триггеры на insert/update, теперь всё ок

Comment: Триггеры это для чего-то совсем древнего